# how can we prove this inequality???

Tags: information-theory

visit this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2279318/446173

due to this answer can we infer this equation? if yes how can we prove this???

$$I((X_1,\dots X_n);(Y_1,\dots Y_n))\ge\sum_{i=1}^n H(Y_i|Y_1\dots Y_{i-1})-H(Y_i|Y_1\dots Y_{i-2},X_1\dots X_n)$$

Comment: this is the chain rule for mutual information and the fact that conditioning reduces entropy

Answer (score 1):

This inequality holds because
$$\begin{split}I(\textbf{X};\textbf{Y})&=H(\textbf{Y})-H(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X})=\sum_{i=1}^nH(Y_i|Y^{i-1})-\sum_{i=1}^nH(Y_i|Y^{i-1},\textbf{X})\\
 \end{split}$$
where $\textbf X = X_1,X_2,...,X_n$, and $\textbf Y = Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$. Then notice that because conditioning decreases entropy,
$$\begin{split}H(Y_i|Y^{i-1},\textbf{X})\leq H(Y_i|Y^{i-2},\textbf{X})\\
 \end{split}$$ so the original inequality is true.

Comment: thanks for your answer. that is true but how can we prove that the left side is greater than right side???

Comment: Thanks for noticing it, I edited the answer